# Quiet beach near Istanbul

Tags: turkey, beaches, istanbul

Are there are any places to have quite relax on the seaside near Istanbul (less than 100 km)? It would be nice to have place to stay for few nights in this location.

Comment: This is a bit wide of an area and asking for an opinion.  Can you clarify the criteria?

Comment: Not really. Istanbul is a huge city, with plenty of things to do. However there is not such much to do and see in the immediate surroundings. Thus a range of 100 km is not excessive.

Comment: @SantaC. 100km from Istanbul you have 2 seas to consider and few hundred km of beachfront, some of which may not be in the tourist guides.  Also car is not the only mode of transport available, so as it stands the range of possible answers may be too wide.

Comment: It is not in the tourist guides because there is strictly nothing to do or to see.

Comment: This seems like it should be answerable to me. Istanbul is anything but quiet and Turkey's famous beach resorts are anything but quiet. So I would assume that rather than there being too many to fit in an answer that there's likely to be very few that fit the criteria. If I'm wrong though I think some minimal proof ought to be shown.

Answer (score 4):

There are two popular options not too far from Istanbul.

- The Princes Islands (Adalar), are a 90 minutes ferry ride from the center of Istanbul. In principle the islands are quiet as there are no private motor vehicles allowed there. However, they can be crowded in July and August. In that period, it is better to avoid going there on a weekend.
- On the Black Sea you can go to Kilyos (40 km from central Istanbul). You can get there by ferry and bus. It's a pleasant trip.

For more information you can have a look at the following page:

http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/Istanbul/Sights/beaches.html

Comment: please comment when you downvote an answer

Comment: They have voted down because the answer is mine. On this site, votes are for persons not for answers or questions.